# Is there any word in English to ask for "whichth"?

Tags: word-request

In my native language, and most Indian languages that I know, there is a way to ask for "whichth", but I don't seem to have found anything similar in English. Let me explain below.

What question would you need to ask to obtain the following answers?

> - In terms of geographical area, Australia is the **sixth** largest country.
> - John is his father's **third** son.
> - Mars is the **fourth** planet in the solar system.

The only way I can think of is use of roundabout legalese-like sentence structure, which makes it sound laughable. For example:

> - If countries are arranged in order of their geographical area, then at what number is Australia?
> - Among the sons of John's father, if you arrange them in the order of birth, then at what number does John appear?
> - At what position is Mars in the solar system, in terms of distance from the Sun?

If there is such a word as "*whichth*", one could ask, for example:

> - Australia is "*whichth*" largest country in terms of geographical area?

Comment: We have that word in my first language too. In a site for native English speakers who want to learn Thai, there is this dialog: *My parents have five children. Which are you?* ;^)

Comment: Whicheth! This sounds like an awesome and useful word.  I vote we unilaterally adopt it in English.  If *selfie* *twerk*, *phablet*, and *apols* (short for apologies (had to look it up)) can make it into Oxford's, then useful words like *whicheth* should stand proudly in their company.

Answer (score 4):

There's no word in English that means exactly "which-th". I would normally say something like the following:

> Where/How does Australia rank against other countries in terms of geographical area?

This sentence uses the phrase "Where does X rank..." or "How does X rank", which works when someone or something is being ranked against other people or things.

> Which planet is Mars, the third or the fourth?

The second sentence uses "which" but adds "the third or the fourth" to clarify exactly what is meant by "which".

> Is John the youngest son, the oldest, or somewhere in the middle?

This last sentence just dodges the problem entirely.

*Note: I would only write the first sentence. The other two are conversational.*

Comment: I thought of using "where" but not "how"! I was going to start the question like :"Where does Australia come [against] the other countries? Because the answer would be something like: It comes e.g. second". It's good to know, and this question is a good one. +1 for the each, the Q and A.