# Which one is correct: "What birthday was it?" or "Which birthday was it?" or "What number birthday was it?"

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language, questions

I have seen this online.

*"The Queen had a birthday, but held no public celebration due to the coronavirus lockdown. What birthday was it?
a. 92nd
b. 94th
c. 96th"*

The sentence **"What birthday was it?**" sounds different to me. I have never seen the word **"what"** being used for asking about ordinal number of something. **"What birthday"** sounds as if you are asking about the type of birthday like "an open air birthday party" or "a birthday at a special place", etc.

As a non-native speaker I would probably say **"Which birthday was it?"** or **"What number birthday was it?** if I am expecting a ordinal number as an answer.

So, I want to make sure if it is perfectly ok to use **"what"** like this to ask about the "ordinal number of something. And I want to ask;

Is **"What birthday was it?"** more idiomatic than **"Which birthday was it?"** or **"What number birthday was it"?**

Comment: No, I don't think it's any more idiomatic than "Which birthday was it?"

Comment: [English, unfortunately, just doesn't have a word for "whichth", although it often seems like it would be useful.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15319/is-there-any-word-in-english-to-ask-for-whichth)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of these to ask about the birthday:

> 1. What birthday was it?
> 2. Which birthday was it?
> 3. What number birthday was it?

Personally, I would say either #2 or #3: **which** because there are a finite number of birthdays and you're choosing one from the list; or **What number** to emphasize you want to know just the number.

#1, however, gives you more flexibility to infer other meaning into your question because it's not as specific as **what number** or **which**. So if you wanted to suggest, for example, that the birthday really didn't exist, you might use #1.